# Edit a query string with htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm having a few issues with my htaccess. I'm trying to remove some MailChimp tags from a query string. The string also has utm tags for mail tracking which I need to leave. After lots of trial and error, I've come up with this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /?(.*)&mc_cid.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1? [R=301,NE]
```

It doesn't seem to have any impact on my site, despite working on https://htaccess.madewithlove.be

EDIT: This has to do with utm tags for email tracking. MailChip are having issues with their RSS emails and are adding their own tracking tags whether or not you want them. A url that this should work with is [https://www.shelleybassett.com/blog/chester/taking-a-trip-to-the-vet/?utm_source=Shelley+Bassett+Design&utm_campaign=125bc6fef0-RSS_FRIDAY_EMAIL_CAMPAIGN&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_fe58f17f17-125bc6fef0-78828913&mc_cid=125bc6fef0&mc_eid=383156c079](https://www.shelleybassett.com/blog/chester/taking-a-trip-to-the-vet/?utm_source=Shelley%20Bassett%20Design&utm_campaign=125bc6fef0-RSS_FRIDAY_EMAIL_CAMPAIGN&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_fe58f17f17-125bc6fef0-78828913&mc_cid=125bc6fef0&mc_eid=383156c079)

My .htaccess file is meant to remove everything after and including &mc_cid. The utm tags need to remain for Google Analytics

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shelleybassett.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.shelleybassett.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RedirectMatch 301 /tag/(.*)/$ /?s=$1

RedirectMatch 301 /disciplines/ /portfolio/
RedirectMatch 301 /collections/ /recipes/
RedirectMatch 301 /family/ /plants/
RedirectMatch 301 /series/ /videos/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /?(.*)&mc_cid.*$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1? [R=301,NE]


#<filesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
#Header set Cache-Control "max-age=84600, public"
#</filesMatch>

## EXPIRES HEADER CACHING ##
#<IfModule mod_expires.c>
#ExpiresActive On
#ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
#ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
#ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
#ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
#ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
#ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
#ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
#ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
#ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
#ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
#ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
#</IfModule>
## EXPIRES HEADER CACHING ##



# BEGIN WP-HUMMINGBIRD-CACHING

# END WP-HUMMINGBIRD-CACHING
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you mean by MailChimp tags? What is your expected output?

Comment: Edited my question with a link and the tags I'm trying to remove

Comment: Sure. It's there now

Comment: Move your redirect rule just below `RewriteBase` line.

Comment: It's kind of working now. But instead of remaining on the correct page, it's redirecting to the homepage... But it has removed the mc_cid stuff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code placed in the mod_rewrite section is

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /?(.*)&mc_cid.*$ 
RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1 [R=301,L]
```

This takes the query and saves the part we want to use.
Then, the uri is saved, and a new url is generated by using the saved uri then adding the part of the query string we want to use. The redirect is 301 (permanent) to tell browsers no one should be seeing the original page, then the rewrite is ended (L flag).